# Scala- writing list to file using foreach

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a list I have into a file and I'm trying to it with the foreach call, as can be done with println.
this works:

```
list.foreach(println)
```

but this won't work:

```
val file = "whatever.txt"
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)))
list.foreach(writer.write)
```

I've tried some other ways to print to a file and in all of them had no luck,
what an I doing wrong?

Comment: "had no luck, what an I doing wrong" Perhaps if you told us what was not working, rather than "won't work" and "no luck" we might be able to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a complete example that compiles and runs. Your code was missing `close()` so everything your wrote in `BufferedWriter` remained in the buffer and never reached the disk.

```
import java.io._

val file = "whatever.txt"
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
List("this\n","that\n","other\n").foreach(writer.write)
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

writer needs to flush to the disk, and then be closed.

```
writer.flush
writer.close
```

Or you can try another way: using PrintWriter

Comment: "does not pass the build " and how were we supposed to know that? Telepathy? Please add the error messages to your question.